# Postfix outbound mail not passing SPF checks for gmail

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

**Scenario**

I've had my mail with mediatemple for years but now that godaddy acquired them they have cut off my outbound mail and when I call in they are pushing microsoft 360 SO I've decided to roll my own mail.

I have postfix setup with spf and all seems well except that gmail shuts down my test emails every time:

```
<x@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.137.27]
    said: 550-5.7.26 This mail is unauthenticated, which poses a security risk
    to the 550-5.7.26 sender and Gmail users, and has been blocked. The sender
    must 550-5.7.26 authenticate with at least one of SPF or DKIM. For this
    message, 550-5.7.26 DKIM checks did not pass and SPF check for
    [ve.x.vesrv.com] 550-5.7.26 did not pass with ip: [x.x.x.x]. The
    sender should visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for 550 5.7.26
    instructions on setting up authentication.
    y14-20020a056a001c8e00b0067f03c85d73si2102348pfw.115 - gsmtp (in reply to
    end of DATA command)
```

**Question**

Mail gets delivered to my own domain, but how can I get it delivered to my gmail address ?

---

*more details*

- **72.x.x.x** is my ubuntu server, which is under the umbrella of **vserv.com**
- **x.com** is my domain

my dns **TXT** record is
v=spf1 ip4:72.x.x.x include:ve.x.vesrv.com include:_spf.google.com -all

and my **main.cf** is

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
#delay_warning_time = 4h
readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ve.6ryrfw2g.vesrv.com
#myhostname = mail.x.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = ve.x.vesrv.com, localhost.x.vesrv.com, , localhost
#mydestination = $myhostname, x.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
#mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $myhostname
#masquerade_domains = x.com
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all

### custom ###

#spf

policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
     ...
     permit_sasl_authenticated
     permit_mynetworks
     reject_unauth_destination
     check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf
     ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting SPF working, I started getting a new response from gmail

```
<xx.xx@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.251.2.26]
    said: 550-5.7.25 [72.x.x.x] The IP address sending this message does not
    have a PTR 550-5.7.25 record setup, or the corresponding forward DNS entry
    does not point 550-5.7.25 to the sending IP. As a policy, Gmail does not
    accept messages from 550-5.7.25 IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit
    550-5.7.25  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#ip-practices for
    more 550 5.7.25 information.
    q25-20020a635059000000b0055384329027si1633035pgl.566 - gsmtp (in reply to
    end of DATA command)
```

As this is an error about reverse DNS not matching I ultimately had to contact GoDaddy, the owner of my ip block, and request that they set up a reverse dns PTR record for my specific IP.